# How to design a poster about posters?

Tags: posters

I was asked to create a poster about posters for a conference poster session. The poster topic is about "unpublished" posters created by Soviet artists during 1985-1991s. I'm completely new to this job. My part is only to arrange text blocks and figures.
So, a few questions arise:

- Can I scan/make photos of these posters and paste them?
- Can I paste only fragments of them? Should I?
- What is the suitable balance between text and pictures?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hope my question complies with the site rules. If not, please let me know to correct it. Thank you.

Comment: This question is entirely too vague. Please provide more information so that specific questions can be answered 'any links/advice' is not the type of question that works with the SE format.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you are making an infographic about creating posters.

I'd start brainstorming about what type of posters you will be making.  That is are they materials for internal use or more marketing to eventual customers.  I like https://bubbl.us/ for brainstorming.

Once you have your target audience that will greatly help what design style the audience may react to.